# Recover file from Windows hard drive using Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, data-recovery

I created a Ubuntu Live CD and I have it running.  The hard drive is mounted and I can see the Windows folder and some backup folders, but not any other folders or files.

How do I get to those?

Comment: Did you by any chance wipe out the partition record? That is recoverable to a point. It would explain why you can't see the drive in the file browser.

Comment: I don't know the circumstances that brought the computer to it's current state; it's a relatives computer.  I can tell you that the Windows recovery disc that came with the PC fails during the process, **BSoD**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file browser you should be able to see a list of "Hard Drives" (which are actually partitions on some drives, but still the icon is the same.  You should be able to click on them to mount the partition and browse the files as normal.  You might need to plug in a USB jump drive or some other storage media to copy the data off of the drive.  If you need more help, you should specify what folders you're after.  Typically there should be a "Documents and Settings" folder on the primary partition and under there are folders for users accounts (including Documents, Music and Desktop folders).

Comment: I do see a "hard drive", but i think it might be the recover partition because it's only backup folders, a system recovery folder, and Windows (just setup files).  I need access to the old c: partition were my files are located.  how can i get access to that?

Comment: Open a Terminal (under Accessories) type `sudo fdisk -l`, that will list out your partitions.  You should see a list of partitions along the line of /dev/sdaX where X is a number.  You can create directories to match those names in your home directory then mount them and examine the folder contents.  ex. If I wanted to create a mount for sda1 I'd do the following: `mkdir ~/sda1`, then `sudo mount /dev/sda1 ~/sda1`, then `cd ~/sda1` and nose about in the directory.  Once mounted you can use the Nautilus browser to view the directories too.